# Two Macs, Both Ventura, Apps launch with "New file" on one, "Open file" on other

Tags: default-settings, application-launch, system-preferences, macos-ventura, computer-behavior

I have two Macs on my desk, one for work and one for personal use.

When I launch an app, say Numbers for example:

- On the work MacBook Pro the application launches and prompts to create a new file from a template.
- On the personal MacBook Air, the applications launches and prompts to open an existing file.

Similar things happen for other apps, QuickTime Player on the work computer just launches, and on the personal computer it asks to open a file.

What do I have set differently between the two? or, how do I change whatever this setting is so that both behave the same?

Comment: Are these both Intel macs or M1 / M2 ? Or different processors ? Which generation ?

Comment: @1NN The work MacBook is an Intel CPU, the personal is an M1 Air. I doubt this is a hardware specific feature since it has to do with app launch and I want to say there used to be a preference somewhere that could set this behavior that is either burried or missing from Settings in Ventura.

Comment: Which of the two behaviors do you prefer ?

Comment: I assume that the Work Macbook Pro has gone through several OS-upgrades and the apps has potentially also gone through these same updates over time. This could simply be backwards compatible linguistic resources or configurations. If you completely remove the app in question on the Macbook Pro, then re-install it, do you experience the same behavior? Also, do the two have the same Locale settings?

Comment: The behavior applies to all apps on each Mac. Each of the macs were originally installed with the previous macOS before Ventura, and then upgraded to Ventura. If there was a setting in System Prefs before Ventura, I can’t find it anymore in Settings.app